Possible faulty python datetime/pytz module behaviour
I think there may be a problem with the pytz/datetime module in python. Either that or I am not using it correctly.
Please look at the coding below which highlights the issues I'm currently facing. I've also given a quick synposis below of the 2 issues I'm having trouble solving at the moment.

The first issue I am facing is that python datetime module seems to think that on that date of 1/4/2024, the london timezone is behind UTC timezone by 1 minute! In actual reality on the 1/4/2024, london timezone is 1 hour ahead of UTC because this when the UK is using DST.

The 2nd issue is that the 'astimezone' method seems to incorrectly convert the london time of midnight on  the 1/4/24 to 3am on the 1/4/24 in the Eastern European Timezone (EET). The correct coverted time should be 2am on the 1/4/2024.


Is the python datetime/pytz module faulty or have I made a simple error somewhere?
Coding:
from datetime import datetime
import pytz

# 1) Creating & outputting datetime object for the date 1/4/2024 in the london timezone
lndn_timezone=pytz.timezone("Europe/London")
lndn_datetime=datetime(2024,4,1,0,0,0,tzinfo=lndn_timezone)
print(lndn_datetime) # This shows that lndn_datetime is 1 minute behind UTC. Why? London time on 1/4/2024 should be UTC+01:00. NOT UTC-00:01 as is displayed.

# 2) Converting lndn_datetime to a datetime in EET (Eastern European Timezone) and displaying result.
eet_timezone=pytz.timezone("EET")
eet_datetime=lndn_datetime.astimezone(eet_timezone)
print(eet_datetime) # This has incorrectly converted london datetime to eet timezone. The result should be 1/4/2024 2am. NOT 3am as is displayed.


You can't assign a pytz timezone in the datetime constructor, it simply doesn't work properly.

If I can't use the pytz timezone in the datetime constructor, I fail to see any alternative solutions to create an aware datetime object that contains timezone information. For example at midgnight on the date of the 1/4/2024 the london timezone should be UTC+01:00. Could you please demonstrate how the datetime module (or any other method/module) can be used to show the correct london timezone information for the given datetime: 1/4/24, 00:00:00? @MarkRansom

You can use localize() on a datetime that doesn't yet contain a timezone.  E.g. lndn_datetime=lndn_timezone.localize(datetime(2024,4,1,0,0,0))
